# Searchable civiEvents in drupal7

Tags: search, civicrm

I have a site that is running on drupal 7 and uses civicrm 4.4.1. I need the events to be included in the search results.

So far all I have found was dated documentation on civicrm that required modules that are not available for Drupal 7.

I also tried the search page module and it is not grabbing the events.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the CiviCRM views integration to create views of the events, and ensure that these are searchable by using the [Search by Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_by_page) module which according to the project page "allows you to index non-Node pages, including user profiles, file attachments, and Views".